# React Native-Styling Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-stylesheet

I want to add custom styles to my tab navigator. I have tried using the `style:{}` inside **screenOptions** but the styles don't work. Only the built in style props work. Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

import Home from './Home'
import Create from './Create'
import Messages from './Messages'
import Forum from './Forum'
import Profile from './Profile'
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (

        <Tabs.Navigator

            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                tabBarShowLabel: false,
                tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
                style: {
                    borderRadius: 15,
                    height: 90,
                },
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                    let iconName;

                    switch (route.name) {
                        case 'Home':
                            iconName = 'home';
                            break;
                        case 'Messages':
                            iconName = 'message-circle';
                            break;
                        case 'Create':
                            iconName = 'home';
                            break;
                        case 'Forum':
                            iconName = 'activity';
                            break;
                        case 'Profile':
                            iconName = 'user';
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    // return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
                    // return <LottieView source={filePath} loop={false} autoPlay={focused} />;
                    return <Icon name={iconName} color={color} size={24} />;
                },
            })}
        >
            <Tabs.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Tabs.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
            <Tabs.Screen name="Create" component={Create} />
            <Tabs.Screen name="Forum" component={Forum} />
            <Tabs.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        </Tabs.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Is there another way to style it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to change the style of `Bottom Navigation` use `tabBarStyle` or `tabBarItemStyle` rather than `style` in screenOptions.

```
  const screenOptions = {
    tabBarStyle:{
      backgroundColor:'#0000ff',
      height:100,
    },
    tabBarItemStyle:{
      backgroundColor:'#00ff00',
      margin:5,
      borderRadius:10,
    }
  };
```

```
  <Tab.Navigator {...{ screenOptions }}>
```

**Ref:** https://snack.expo.dev/@fanish/native-stack-navigator-%7C-react-navigation

Comment: I tried the following solution i have 4 tab navigators and its only working on 2 of them

Comment: @kd12345 same here, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use a custom tab bar us the tabBar props.

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}>
  {...}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `tabBarLabelStyle`:

```
<Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName='AnyNav'
        screenOptions={{
          
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#000',
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            fontWeight: '900',
          },
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
...
```